# WP8 : WebClient API DownloadStringAsync throwing System.Net.WebException when downloading any RSS feed

Tags: windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm trying to download an RSS feed in my WP8 app using the WebClient api and is getting a System.Net.WebException: NotFound, I tried it various different RSS feeds and the result is the same, am I missing something, here is the sample code

```
public class RssFeedDownloader
{
    public Task<string> GetRssFeed(string feedUrl)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetException(e.Error);
            }
        };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(feedUrl));

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL? Have you confirmed you can access the URL from the IE web browser for example?

Comment: Yeah IE its fine, as I mentioned in the post, seems like any RSS feed URL I use basically getting the same issue

Comment: is the url by any chance https?

Comment: Works for me, first try. So, what's a URL that is failing?

Comment: No Https, URLs are basically following "http://feeds.feedburner.com/sermons-audio?fmt=xml";
        "http://feeds.feedburner.com/occ/aHAW?fmt=xml"

Comment: I think somethings up with networking inside of emulator, I can't see to browse any sites using the IE